# How to download file from Podio?

Tags: file, podio

I use the API developer from Podio and get the files URL as:
https://files.podio.com/1394450000

Downloading with access token sent gives me an a Login Page (Unauthorized).

How to download file with HTTP API?

PS: I previously logged in with my data to obtain the token with
auth_url = 'https://podio.com/oauth/token'

```
auth_data = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'username': username,
    'password': password
}
```

and the token is working ok for obtain data which comes from https://api.podio.com, but not working for files on https://files.podio.com/1394450000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the access_token you generated from the /token endpoint and add it to the `oauth_token` parameter to authenticate the download of a file.

```
https://files.podio.com/1394450000?oauth_token=<access_token>
```

Comment: I send the access token in the Authorization header like: `Authorization OAuth2 <access_token>` which works, I didn't know you could send the token in the querystring.